# Python - invalid syntax error

Tags: python, pandas

I am learning python , and I am running below code :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame( [['A',20,30],['B',30,40]],index=['A1','B1'],columns = ['a','b','c'])

df1.loc['A1':'B1',['a':'b']] #edit to df1 to make easier for answerers
```

It is giving syntax error : invalid syntax (at ':' after 'a')

Whats wrong with this?

Comment: Maybe you want `'a':'b'` rather than `['a':'b']` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to give it a *slice* object, as per the [documentation here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html). So `df1.loc['A1':'B1','a':'b']` works. Note that you want `df1.` not `df.`.

> Allowed inputs are:
>
> - A single label, e.g. 5 or 'a', (note that 5 is interpreted as a label of the >index, and never as an integer position along the index).
> - A list or array of labels, e.g. ['a', 'b', 'c']
> - A slice object with labels, e.g. 'a':'f'.